# Safely casting mixed type into appropiate type with flow

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, flowtype

Say I am returned some random object data. Now I wish validate and cast it to the appropiate type for use in the rest of my application. To do this I wrote the following utilty function.

```
static convertSingleSafe<T: (number | boolean | string | void)>(
        data: {[string]: mixed},
        name: string,
        type: 'number' | 'boolean' | 'string' | 'object' | 'undefined'): T {
    if (typeof data[name] === type ) {
        return data[name]
    } else  {
        throw new KeyError(`Badly formated value ${name}`, '')
    }
}
```

Which would be called like:

```
const data: {[string]: mixed} = {val: 10, otherdata: 'test'};
//data would come from IE JSON.parse() of a request to server.
const val: number = convertSingleSafe<number>(data, 'val', 'number');
const msg: string = convertSingleSafe<string>(data, 'otherdata', 'string);
```

The problem, however, with this is that flow doesn't seem to understand the assertions in the `convertSingleSafe` function. On `return data[name]` the following error is shown:

> Error:(82, 20) Cannot return `data[name]` because: Either mixed [1] is incompatible with number [2]. Or mixed [1] is incompatible with boolean [3]. Or mixed [1] is incompatible with string [4].

Even though I quite explicitly test the value for that specific.

---

The other option, to let the generic be part of the data type gives the following error:

```
static convertSingleSafe<T: (number | boolean | string | void)>(
        data: {[string]: T},
        name: string,
        type: 'number' | 'boolean' | 'string' | 'object' | 'undefined'): T
```

> Error:(191, 41) Cannot call `FlowTest.convertSingleSafe` with `d` bound to `data` because in the indexer property: Either mixed [1] is incompatible with number [2]. Or mixed [1] is incompatible with boolean [3]. Or mixed [1] is incompatible with string [4].

So (how) can I do this, without going through `any` casts?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you've gotta understand about [type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) in flow is that it's not very smart. Flow is basically looking for a construction like `typeof <something> === 'number'`, like imagine it's using regular expressions to scan your code (this is not actually the case). [Here's](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygZRmAcwBt0cBDYdACgChF6H6ATMqMgLkQG8BtAZyiZ8BALqcAtjAAe6JgF8ANHUYMwZcek4ChhJSoZQAngAdNiAORgQ4gEZZziAD4WbcOCTJgHz89uHeLOBsAK3RoAPNwJnRgfFlzGgBKTitbLCdEV3d0Twy-QgyuOSdUOBgmbmV6FDABRD4QELCoRABeRBY2HjUNEQBuKsQYYEQqI1M21vbLaztMBwAyBcRx9DgRhqboSenUufNEyv1MdCgQTCRN0OgBxjlB4dHVnZc3Dy9EJZWTNY3G65aU2mWXeByOKhOZwu9X+zVuDHujEeYx+L18gn8n2Wq3WMK2gKmFnyBDBXEG9Eh50usJug0RDGRzyBFiiMTiTEW2J+uKuzTRrNiYHihzJx1OVLxAPh9Hp9EZqOZ5iCAM5kr5Xxxf3xaOVzVJ5MQlOhvNpd0GUAAFpg4AB3RBCu0AUUw1swVAABgAhMhMIiGRDAOCYcSsWSIVBkIggdCIAAkXB66Dk7sSNHuNBqGGweEIJHIlCoXEQHEQAEZEIoLGRzAoLHt7Ik+kA) an example that does what I think you want:

```
static convertSingleSafe(
  data: {[string]: mixed},
  name: string,
  type: 'number' | 'boolean' | 'string' | 'object' | 'undefined'
): number | boolean | string | {} | void {
  const subject = data[name];
  if (type === 'number' && typeof subject === 'number') {
    return subject;
  }
  if (type === 'boolean' && typeof subject === 'boolean') {
    return subject;
  }
  if (type === 'string' && typeof subject === 'string') {
    return subject;
  }
  if (type === 'undefined' && typeof subject === 'undefined') {
    return subject;
  }
  if (type === 'object' && subject && typeof subject === 'object') {
    return subject;
  }
  throw new KeyError(`Badly formated value ${name}`, '');
}
```

And [here's the generic version](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygZRmAcwBt0cBDYdAHgChFEAVALkQBIAldMgEwHkwiATyoBvANoBnKJnwEAuizAgAtgCMsiAD6JVcOCTJJtUmYS2IRAX3Oo4MbpYB8AGkR1EAORYnZzmo8QACnduMigyFgY-ejAyZXQWD2jEKEEABwTEAHIlNSws8yzdfS4wAu0sn0Jy7LhVACt0aBqs8G50YHx0biyaAEoWVgBREniwKAZ06ijPAJF3FDApRAkQBqaoRABeRFDwsVj4uQBudxhgINSM7a2dnJV1TAKAMmeUqbgL1fXoG7vcx5ZPoWdz0TDoKAgTBIb6NaCneiWM4XQJXdB-bLFAxlRCvd4ZT4rNZwza3O5Y0pAkH0MEQqEw4kbBGIJH0c6XKYYyrSWQvN5owmwjZcqoEKnzGmIcGQ6FEn5QZmsxDs1GcsnZNodLo9XH8j5fRm-dWtMDtTpgbri0FSumyoXw9xKlVorl1El8uUk3X49CCw2k261eVWyXS+mepmO9xQAAWmDgAHdEBak0NMPHMIEAAYAIR4QkQwDgmGUYW6iFQZCIIHRrBEh3QlizfVOllONAA9B3MQULd0JCk4Dp0UQYFAsFXXGPkIYspsY2QMD7EFnRVmaItlgQ9NwPA8sIp95htsg0FhcLISORKIERBFsuOpFlXKoWABGSyuIrP7IA-Itztu2GAAPDJoDTDMNwQZZVB4HAeUIbwEIIE9FgwbA8EIK8KHQW97zndAnxfd9Px7L8-yeACoKWTZtzgbh4NMAgkKY1Czwwy9SBwvCWAIoidBIr8yB-bkmKBU4uzYIZQI2CDi2omCeD3PJMEPFS2LAdCLywribzvXjHygH9X0QD8hJE0VxJoBTaJ3RjZAAJhY2QNK0zDiF03D9IfQijOI0zSMCLJhOcwg+i-SyAMk2MYAHCQYzgEAiG4RAsAzHQQE2aduDgQiyk2dQIDIEAJHRBtlQHMgVmQ1wwDgTYqtHcdMCrGydCUo8nOTI9XPPdzsL0-DDOMwSgmCrJQoIcLski04gA).

Comment: Doesn't work if you try to assign to a typed var, such as `const a: number = convertSingleSafe({ a: 1 }, 'a', 'number');`

Comment: Added generic version to the answer because the link is too long for a comment. You'd want something like that.